# python timer thread sleep not working properly

Tags: python, multithreading, time, timer

I'm looking for a way to make a python thread wait/sleep for an amount of time, I'm using

```
time.sleep (10.0)
```

but it doesn't sleep for 10 seconds, it sleeps for less than that. I read [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2006-November/050915.html) as well as in some other places that it may sleep less or more than the amount specified in duration. Is there another way of doing or fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the example of usage of [`signal.alarm`](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html#example).  It might give you the needed functionality.